# Open access database without executing scripts or forms

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to troubleshoot an MS Access XP database and the first thing it does it close the main window and prompt for a date. Everything I enter comes with an error message stating that the value entered is not a valid date mm/dd/yyyy. It then proceeds to close access. I've tried every date format I can think of to no avail.

Is it possible to open an access database without it automatically prompting me for some input and closing? At this point I have no idea what is going underneath the hood of this thing since I can't even open it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hold the Shift-key down when you choose open in the file menu in Access.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a wireless keyboard, holding the shift key may sometimes not work.  Try holding the shift key on your laptop's keyboard while double-clicking or hitting the enter button to open Access without running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get in, you may want to either get rid of the macro name 'autoexec' or under Tools | Startup remove the selected item for 'Display Form/Page' set it to (None).