# How to bypass MSAccss AutoExec macro and bypass Startup form

Tags: vba, ms-access, autoexec

How do I bypass the MSAccess autoexec macro and startup form for a deep-legacy code upgrade of a large MS Access 2003 application with hundreds of forms and reports?

It is an upgrade from Access 2003 to Access 2016, 2019 or 365.

This is a mission critical system kept alive and on crutches for 15 years without any VBA code updates.

- Files in the application

  - Multiple MSAccess files in MDB and ACCDB format
  - No MSAccess files in MDE or ACCDE formats with compiled VBA code
  - No MSAccess other files wuch as mdw security files
- I run a dos command for the database - PATH_TO_MSACCESS.exe DB_NAME.mdb
- I'm using MSAccess.exe 32 bit from Office 365.

  - Note that there are compatibility and VBA compiler errors if you run on a 64 bit MSAccess.exe if the VBA calls Windows operating system Win32 API methods.  This app calls a few (5) Win32 API calls.  Technical, MS Access 64 bit will treat some 32 bit data sent in/returned from the Win32 API as 64 bit causing errors.

The most difficult part is that many of the web pages and nearly all Microsoft pages related to this have been deleted from the web.

---

- Tried but did not work

  - Holding down shift key when you open the MSAccess database
  - Hitting F11 to open the Navigation Pane in Access (does not open).  If Navigation Pane opens I could edit the AutoExec macro or the startup form's Form_Open code
- Tried, not perfect, and works

  - Run a macro which does not exist on MSAccess.exe command line, hit escape multiple times on the error messages, the click on the MSAccess ribbon to get to the VBA code. Messy, but it gets me into the VBA code.

    - Added a "Stop" as the first line of the macro named "autoexec" and also as the first line of the startup form's "Form_Open()" method.  I had to add an empty "Form_Open()" event handler for the form

---

Current status:

- The application runs OK on a machine with MS Access version before 2016
- It fails multiple ways when only 32 bit MS Access 365/2019 is installed on the machine.

  - I have been finding and fixing things like bad configuration file entries, incorrect installation path, etc. but need to debug the VBA startup code and initial form load in the VBA debugger.

    - I cannot directly get into the VBA debugger on the first line of the AutoExec macro or start up form's Form_Open function.  MSAccess always runs the autoexec macro and shows the startup form.

      - I can get into the VBA by running MSaccess.exe command line and specifying that it runs a macro which does not exist.

Here are possible solutions based on Google searching broken out by Access version since the code/database settings in question could be specific to any Access version from 95 to 2010.

---

Access 2007: [Opening an MS-Access database from the command line without running any of the startup vba code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657263/opening-an-ms-access-database-from-the-command-line-without-running-any-of-the-s)
Hold down shift key when opening MDB database

---

Access XP
[Open access database without executing scripts or forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493129/open-access-database-without-executing-scripts-or-forms)

- Hold down shift key when opening the Access database
- Remove AutoExec macro
- Remove the startup form setting from the database

---

Access 2007:
[Emulating a SHIFT key press when using VBA to open an ms-access database secured by an mdw file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674472/emulating-a-shift-key-press-when-using-vba-to-open-an-ms-access-database-secured)

- Slightly different case where the Access database is secured by a MDW security file
- Same answers

---

Access XP/2003/2007?
[How to skip Autoexec macro when opening MSAccess from MSAccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422173/how-to-skip-autoexec-macro-when-opening-msaccess-from-msaccess)

- Method One:

  - Original URL is dead, Internet Archive Wayback machine has an archived copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20101204113950/http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0068.htm
  - Send Shift key to Access via code to bypass startup macro if the [AllowbypassKey] is not set
- Method Two:

  - Extract the Autoexec macro from the database, replace it with a blank AutoExec macro
  - Uses DoCmd.DatabaseTransfer acImport and DoCmd.DatabaseTransfer acExport
- Method Three:

  - Rename the AutoExec macro using VBA code
  - OpenCurrentDatabase ("Your database")
  - DoCmd.Rename "Autoexec", acMacro, "tmp_Autoexec"
  - CloseCurrentDatabase

---

MS Access keyboard short cuts for getting at the VBA code or objects in an Access database. From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-70a673e4-4f7b-4300-b8e5-3320fa6606e2
I haven't tried the MSAccess keyboard short cuts to see if they let me open and view the Access VBA code, toolbars, table/form dedign viewer, or switch to code editing mode.   I've included them here for completeness.

- F2 - Switch between Edit mode (with insertion point displayed) and Navigation mode in the Datasheet or Design view
- F4 - Open properties pane for an object
- F5 - Switch to Form view from the form Design view
- F6 - Switch between panes in the MS Access interface
- F10 (?) unhide the ribbon
- F11 - Show or hide the Navigation Pane
- Alt-X, Alt-X,1 - Open the External Data tab in the ribbon
- Alt-Y - Open the Database Tools tab in the ribbon
- Alt-J,T - Open the Table tab in the ribbon
- Alt-X,2 - Open the Add-ins tab in the ribbon
- Control-F1 - Expand/collapse the ribbon
- Alt-F11 - Switch to/from the VBA editor

---

Show or hide the MSAccess ribbon toolbar in VBA code.  Included here for completeness.  This application hides the ribbon bar on application startup.
[MSAccess - Minimize the Toolbar Ribbon OnLoad()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240240/msaccess-minimize-the-toolbar-ribbon-onload)

- MSAccess 2010 onwards.  The acToolbarNo is in the VBA code for this application

  - DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo    'Hides the full toolbar
  - DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes   'Show
- MSACcess 2010, 2013

  - CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
- Before MSAccess 2010

  - SendKeys "^{F1}", False

---

Special case: You may get an error on the Access startup form if it has a record source which has an error.  this is not the case for my application but included here completeness
[difficulty tracing microsoft access VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644107/difficulty-tracing-microsoft-access-vba-code)

---

Special case: You get an infinite loop of dialog prompts or errors from the startup form.  Hold down the "Control-Break" key while clicking on OK for the error message to break out of the loop of errors. https://bettersolutions.com/vba/debugging/index.htm

---

It may be possible to break out of the main startup form to the MS Access object explorer by right clicking on the startup form's title bar or right click on the startup form's body.

- Right clicking on the startup form's title bar has these menu commands

  - Save
  - Close and Close All
  - Form View
  - Layout View
  - Design View
- Right clicking on the startup form's body has these menu commands

  - Form View
  - Layout View
  - Design View
  - Cut, Copy, Past (disabled)
  - Form Properties (disabled)
  - Properties (disabled)
  - Close

Comment: It's more complicated because the answers are from Access 97, 200, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2016 and the VBA documentation is non-existent as Microsoft removed most of it

Comment: *Tried but did not work* what did not work? Code still ran?

Comment: There are thousands of repeat web pages of how to bypass MSAccess AutoExec macro and bypass he MSAccess startup form on the web. Microsoft really missed the boat in making MSAccess and VBA actually developer friendly (easy source code control, export all code as a project, build/import VBA as a project, ...) without using broken in 2 years mom and pop third party tools.

Comment: I'd appreciate any suggestions how to get at and modify the startup VBA code to insert a "stop" statement as the first line of VBA code executed.  Stop statement will invoke the VBA debugger.

Comment: Solutions were added based on Access version since this code was originally written in Access 95 then upgraded multiple times to Access 2010.  There is code specific to most of the Access versions from 95 to 2010.

Answer (score 2):

the other thing to check? Are you using a shortcut? if it has the /runtime swtich in it, then  the shift key will be ignored NO MATTER what you do, and even if no shfit key by-pass code (to disable) shift key means the shift key will STILL be ignored. So, you want to ensure that you not launching/using a shortcut.

you also want to check/ensure/find out/be aware if the application has workgroup security. Again, in 99 out of 100 cases, the shortcut will show this.

next up:
is this a mdb, or mde file? The mde file is a compiled version. No source code exists, and you can't modify the mde. So, again, ensure that you have a mdb file for the front end, not a mde. If you don't have that mdb, then you are in big trouble - you don't have the source code.

You have all this info in your post, but you leave out the most important issues.
So, is this a mde, or mdb? You need to know this.
Is there a worgroup security file (mdw) specifed in the link that is typical used to launch the application.  If workgroup secuirty is involed, then the logon id you use might get you past shift key, but then that user might not have been given design rights, so at that point, shify key by-pass will be of zero use to get into the code.

I mean, launch your copy of access 2016 or whatever. Then try to import the objects from that database. This way you don't have to use or ever worry about shfit key, but are doing a simple import of the forms, reports and code into a brand new fresh database.

So, another question:
Don't bother launching the application - create a blank new database, and then import from the existing - can you do this? (doing this does NOT copy the shift key setting of the original database).

Comment: The main question is updated to answer your questions.  Good questions and points of refinement.

Comment: a SIMPLE import into a new blank database will remove any startup code options. So this "huge" search about worry of startup options and shift key by-pass is 100% ignored by a simple import into a fresh new blank database.

Answer (score 1):

MSAccess command line lets you tell it what macro to execute on startup.

I ran the following cmd.exe command line which generates multiple errors and allows you to get into the Access database with the navigator and get into the VBA code.  Not the best solution but one possibility.

MSAccess.exe DB /X ADEEERETDEREAR

DB is the full path to the Access database
ADEERETDEREAR is a macro which does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Access 2007?
[How to disable Macro and Start-Up values while opening the MS Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684774/how-to-disable-macro-and-start-up-values-while-opening-the-ms-access-db)

Access 2003?

- Bypasss shift key.  These link to Zip files projects available for download
- https://web.archive.org/web/20071214172548/http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/msaccess/msaccess.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20071214172548/http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/msaccess/shiftkey.zip
- https://web.archive.org/web/20071214172548/http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/msaccess/shiftkey2000.zip

Access 2007:

- [remove autoexec macro from MS Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509307/remove-autoexec-macro-from-ms-access-2007)
- Create new macro and then rename it in the Access UI to autoexec, say yes to the prompt to overwrite the existing AutoExec macro

Access 2010?

- [Opening an MS-Access database from the command line without running any of the startup vba code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657263/opening-an-ms-access-database-from-the-command-line-without-running-any-of-the-s)

Access ?

- [Disable F11 Key in MS Access to prevent opening the Navigation Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093437/disable-f11-key-in-ms-access-to-prevent-opening-the-navigation-pane)
- Open the Access database, let the main form be shown
- Hit F11 to show the navigation pane
- A guess that one could modify the autoexec macro and/or the startup form from the navigation pane

Access ?

- https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/211664-programatically-set-startup-form
- A guess that you could use VBA in one Access database to open the target database
- Get the name of the startup form
- Change the startup form's name or maybe blank out the startup form's name
- VBA code similar to CurrentDB.Properties("StartupForm") = "MyForm"
- Another guess would be to blank out the startup form's name in the database properties
- Same may work for the autoexec macro

Comment: those links are really old! - but the links are the same, but now on www.kallal.ca/msaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Access 2010?

- Reset startup form to nothing in VBA code
- Code from 2012 is here: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1673392
- First way

  ```
  Dim strOriginalForm as String
  Dim db as Database

  Sub RemoveStartup()
    Set db = OpenDatabase(yourdatabase)
    strOriginalForm = db.Properties("StartUpForm") 
    db.Properties("StartUpForm") = "(none)"
    db.Close
    set db = Nothing
  End Sub

  Sub ResetStartup()
    Set db = OpenDatabase(yourdatabase)
    db.Properties("StartUpForm") = strOriginalForm
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
  End Sub
  ```

Second way

```
Set prp = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", dbBoolean, True)
db.Properties.Append prp
```

Third way
Delete the property using - database.properties.delete propertyname

A more complete example from the same page exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to import the Access objects into a new database.  (Thanks Albert Kallal for the information)

This would allow me to look at the VBA code.  It may not work as a replacement for the original database with all of the settings internal to the database.

How to import the Access objects from another Access database:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-database-objects-into-the-current-access-database-23aea08b-7487-499d-bdce-0c76bedacfdd

- Access 365 steps (likely works for Access 2016)
- External Data tab in ribbon
- Click New Data Source -> From Database -> Access in the Import & Link ribbon group
- Get External Data - Access Database window is shown
- Browse for the MSAccess database MDB or ACCDB file in the File Name Field
- The Import Objects window is shown
- Select the tables, queries, forms, reports macros, modules to import
- In the Options button dialog, you can select menus, toolbars, etc. to import
- Click on OK
- For Names duplicated, Access will append a 1,2,3 to the end of an imported object's name

Answer (score 0):

Access 2010?

- Reset startup form to nothing in VBA code
- Code from 2012 is here: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1673392

Fourth way as mentioned above

A more complete example from the same page.

- Code from 2012 is here: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1673392

```
Public Sub GetCBs()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strPath As String
Dim startUpform As String
Dim app As Access.Application
Dim custBars As Collection
Dim custShortCutBars As Collection
Dim custNonShortCutBars As Collection
Dim i As Integer
Dim blnAutoexec As Boolean
strPath = GetOpenFile()
'Get the db without opening in application
Set db = getDb(strPath)
'Get startupform
startUpform = getStartUp(db)
'Turn off the start up form
TurnOffStartUp db
'Check for and auto exec. If exists import and replace
If hasAutoexec(db) Then
blnAutoexec = True
ImportAutoExec (strPath)
End If
Set app = New Access.Application
'Open safely
app.OpenCurrentDatabase (strPath)
'Read command bars
Set custBars = getCustBars(app)
Set custShortCutBars = getCustShortCutBars(app)
Set custNonShortCutBars = getCustNonShortCutBars(app)
app.CloseCurrentDatabase
Set db = app.CurrentDb
Set db = getDb(strPath)
'Return start up form
TurnOnStartUp db, startUpform
db.Close
'Return auto exec
If blnAutoexec Then
    ReturnAutoExec (strPath)
End If
Debug.Print "all custom bars:"
'All bars
For i = 1 To custBars.Count
    Debug.Print custBars(i)
Next i
'Do something with the command bars
Debug.Print "all shortcut bars:"
'Short cut only
For i = 1 To custShortCutBars.Count
    Debug.Print custShortCutBars(i)
Next i
'Not short cut
Debug.Print "Non shortCut"
For i = 1 To custNonShortCutBars.Count
    Debug.Print custNonShortCutBars(i)
Next i
End Sub

Public Function getDb(strPath As String) As DAO.Database
Set getDb = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(strPath)
End Function

Public Function getCustBars(app As Access.Application) As Collection
' all bars
Dim col As New Collection
Dim cb As Object
For Each cb In app.CommandBars
    If cb.BuiltIn = False Then
        col.Add (cb.Name)
    End If
Next cb
Set getCustBars = col
End Function

Public Function getCustShortCutBars(app As Access.Application) As Collection
' only short cut bars
Dim col As New Collection
Dim cb As commandbar
For Each cb In app.CommandBars
    If cb.BuiltIn = False Then
    If cb.Type = msoBarTypePopup Then
        col.Add (cb.Name)
    End If
    End If
Next cb
Set getCustShortCutBars = col
End Function

Public Function getCustNonShortCutBars(app As Access.Application) As Collection
' Menu bars that are not shortcut bars
Dim col As New Collection
Dim cb As commandbar
For Each cb In app.CommandBars
    If cb.BuiltIn = False Then
    If cb.Type <> msoBarTypePopup Then
        col.Add (cb.Name)
    End If
    End If
Next cb
Set getCustNonShortCutBars = col
End Function

Public Function getStartUp(db As DAO.Database) As String
Dim prp As DAO.Property
For Each prp In db.Properties
    If prp.Name = "startupform" Then
    getStartUp = prp.Value
    Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function

Public Sub TurnOffStartUp(db As DAO.Database)
Dim prp As DAO.Property
For Each prp In db.Properties
    If prp.Name = "startupform" Then
        prp.Value = "(None)"
    Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub

Public Sub TurnOnStartUp(db As DAO.Database, strFrm As String)
Dim prp As DAO.Property
For Each prp In db.Properties
    If prp.Name = "startupform" Then
    prp.Value = strFrm
    Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub

Public Sub ImportAutoExec(strPath As String)
    On Error GoTo errLbl
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", strPath, acMacro, "AutoExec", "AutoExecBackup"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", strPath, acMacro, "TempAutoExec", "AutoExec"
    Exit Sub
errLbl:
If Err.Number = 7874 Then
        Debug.Print "Auto Exec macro does not exist"
    Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ReturnAutoExec(strPath As String)
On Error GoTo errLbl
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", strPath, acMacro, "AutoExecBackup", "AutoExec"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acMacro, "AutoExecBackup"
    Exit Sub
errLbl:
If Err.Number = 7874 Then
        Debug.Print "Auto Exec macro does not exist"
    Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub

Public Function hasAutoexec(db As DAO.Database) As Boolean
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "SELECT MSysObjects.Name FROM MSysObjects WHERE MSysObjects.Name = 'AutoExec' AND MSysObjects.Type = -32766"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    hasAutoexec = True
End If
End Function
```